# Subversion upgrade concerns going from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Subversion 1.6's working copy metadata was stored at each directory in the whole working copy, i.e. each directory would have a ".svn" directory in it. A nice side effect of this was that I could easily just copy out any subdirectory in a working copy and it itself will be its own working copy.

In Subversion 1.7, the working copy metadata structure has changed such that only the top-level directory will have a ".svn" folder for the whole working copy. If you do a "svn info" on a sub-directory, it will still be able to detect that it is part of a working copy, so I assume that svn will traverse upwards until it hits a ".svn" in a parent directory or hits the root of the file hierarchy. But if I copy out that sub-directory somewhere else, it will no longer have this relationship anymore. Not that it's a problem in most cases, but I lose the nice side effect I referred to above.

Is there a way for the svn client to export out a subdirectory working copy from a local working copy without having to go back to the server? The reason why I'm trying to do this is because for our svn repo, doing an initial checkout goes into 50gigs, causing a huge load on the network. I used to pass around a relatively recent working copy on a hard disk to any new joiner to copy into his laptop as a jumpstart of sorts. I have the entire repo in this hard disk, but some people only need specific sub-directories so being able to create a sub-directory working copy would be a nice bonus.

Thanks,
Wong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for the svn client to export out a subdirectory working copy from a local working copy without having to go back to the server?

No.

But you have at least two choices

- Create your checkout with 1.6 client, give subdir(s) to joners,. which they upgrade to 1.7
- Joiner can checkout only `<needed dirs>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do an SVN checkout of that folder specifically.
if there are any local changes, you can then overwrite with the new files